# asp.net DropDownList control type ahead text or value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, dropdown, typeahead

I have an asp.net DropDownList (in a gridview) and user can begin typing and if there's something in the dropdownlist that matches, it will be selected in the dropdownlist.  The dropdownlist is displaying DataTextField values.  I've also specified an associated DataValueField for the dropdown.  Might there be a way that the user could begin typing either a value that might be in the DataTextField or DataValueField and the appropriate DataTextField value would be selected?